# Hosting MVC 4 application on IIS error 500 due to class library reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

When i deploy my mvc 4 application to IIS locally it works. However when i deploy my mvc 4 app on another server it throws 500.

Now the issue here is that my MVC 4 application is using a class library as a database layer which is stopping it from running when its deployed on a remote server. I Tested this by deploying a default mvc 4 application on the server without a class library it launched fine.
But when i reference a class library(empty class library) and redeployed it stopped working (error 500).

The local copy is true on my class library. not sure why IIS doesn't like it.

Am i missing some obvious here?

Comment: Do you deploy the class library dll also?

Comment: Hi, yes the class libraries gets bundled up in bin folder. When the application is published